# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::created_at() (View: D:\project laravel\blog\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have problem like title above, and here is my code below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGkRF.png)

Please help me to solve it

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Comment: `created_at` is not a method but a model property so remove  `()` and you should be good

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can then start writing an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [mre] to improve it before submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think created_at is property of $post[0]

Try `$post[0]->created_at` (remove `()`)